# How to synchronize audio in Android development

Tags: java, android, audio, synchronization

I am a freshman in android development field and lack of experience since I just had four months development experience till now. Here is a kind of tough demand for me and I sincerely hope that there is anyone who can provide me some solution since I totally got no idea.

Here is the background: there is a page named ReciteActivity in which you can recite text and the device will firstly record and then rewrite and store the text at last.Then you could go to Reply page in which you can see the text you recited displayed on the screen and listen to the corresponding audio record.
Now we got a new demand that is, let us take a example, the audio record starts from the second paragraph if you press the second paragraph on the screen, which means the audio record needs to do a synchronization with the specified paragraph.

Hope this question is explicitly clarified and look forward to getting an effective solution from you smart guys in stackoverflow. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the recording one long autio-track, or cut-up into discrete paragraph blocks?  I guess after detecting the click event, the code could start playing from an offset int he audio track.  Then each paragraph only needs to know its audio offset time.

Comment: Firstly thanks for you kind comment. According to your comment，I guess it may needs back-end developers' cooperation？

Comment: Unless the document's paragraphs can be created with their own audio files - yes.

Comment: You mean each paragraph should has a corresponding audio file,which means the audio record should be made up of several separate segments?

Comment: Well it's hard to know based on a short description, so I am guessing, but Yes.